# Dividing two data frames by common rows in R

Tags: r

I have 2 data sets

```
> df2<-data.frame(name=c("A","B","C"),F1=c(5,8,9),F2=c(3,8,9),F3=c(1,2,3))
  name F1 F2 F3
1    A  5  3  1
2    B  8  8  2
3    C  9  9  3
> df1<-data.frame(name=c("C","C","A","B"),F1=c(1,5,8,9),F2=c(1,5,8,9),F3=c(1,5,8,9))
  name F1 F2 F3
1    C  1  1  1
2    C  5  5  5
3    A  8  8  8
4    B  9  9  9
```

I want to divide df1 by df2 by common name ( like C/C, C/C, A/A, B/B). This is only example of my data set which is 250x50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use join and divide with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- names(df1)[-1]
nm2 <- paste0('i.', nm1)
setDT(df1)[df2, (nm1) := Map(`/`, mget(nm1), mget(nm2)), on = .(name)]
df1
#   name        F1        F2        F3
#1:    C 0.1111111 0.1111111 0.3333333
#2:    C 0.5555556 0.5555556 1.6666667
#3:    A 1.6000000 2.6666667 8.0000000
#4:    B 1.1250000 1.1250000 4.5000000
```

Comment: @TanyaValkanova  Yes just replace `/` with `*`

Answer (score 2):

Note that this won't work if any of your real data's names contain `".x"` or `".y"`.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = 'name') %>% 
  {cbind(.['name'], .[grep('.x', names(.))]/.[grep('.y', names(.))])} %>% 
  setNames(names(df1))

#   name        F1        F2        F3
# 1    C 0.1111111 0.1111111 0.3333333
# 2    C 0.5555556 0.5555556 1.6666667
# 3    A 1.6000000 2.6666667 8.0000000
# 4    B 1.1250000 1.1250000 4.5000000
```

Comment: All these solutions will work for multiplying if you replace `/` with `*`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a base R solution:

```
ind = match(df1$name, df2$name)
data.frame("name" = df1$name, df1[,-1] / df2[ind,-1])

#   name        F1        F2        F3
# 1    C 0.1111111 0.1111111 0.3333333
# 2    C 0.5555556 0.5555556 1.6666667
# 3    A 1.6000000 2.6666667 8.0000000
# 4    B 1.1250000 1.1250000 4.5000000
```